# Printing Multiple Columns on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

First of all, my Crystal Reports is in Portuguese which is my mother language. So I am sorry in advance.

I am trying to use Mailing Labels from Crystal Reports to have multiple columns. I was able to set it up and I do it on the Design Mode, but when I change to the Preview Mode labels won't replicate.

This is how set it on the Preview Mode:

[image]

This is how it shows on the Preview Mode:
[image]

I think I've tried everything, changed all the properties, but I can't understand why it is not working. If you look at my Section Expert of Details and even though it is in Portuguese I don't think there is nothing wrong.
[image]

Here it is the Layout properties:
[image]

I don't know if there's any tip you could give me, but I would appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sort direction option from vertical first and Horizontal second to Horizontal First and Vertical Second.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your report has multiple records.

Comment: You're right!! It solved my problem, BUT the main goal of this label is only to show one product. The person will select the product code and it should replicate for the other columns.​